# How to stop single line entry in the input form field

Tags: python, html, css, flask

[image]

if i add content in the input field without any space then view is as shown in the picture. is there any way to stop user to add content as a single line entry?

Comment: Are you trying to stop users from entering new lines? Are you trying to allow users to input multiple lines? What do you mean by "stop user to add content as a single line entry"

Comment: i have a input text area where user can enter text but if user just press a key lets say "k" and dont leave the key until maxlength reached and then view it then it looks like what i post earlier. i want to stop it happening.

Comment: So basically a larger letter like 'k' or 'm' results in bad formatting in the view? Reduce the max-length or change the formatting/css style to adjust font size based on the length?

Comment: sorry i think i was unable to explain the issue. i have created an application where user can added cooking recipes. so in the add recipes input form fields if user enter some text for example (This is a famous recipes form latin america. it based on chicken fillet. it is cooked in old traditional way etc so on ) then if we view view the recipe the text is automatically shown in the lines. but if user enter input in the input field like (kkkkkkkkkk) or (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa) and dont give any space in between the letter then in the view section the text appear just one line and overflow the box.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to let the user add content on multiple lines, but that is not a python question. It is rather something related to HTML, more specifically to your input field.

The input field is called `textarea` and by definition is:

> The  tag defines a multi-line text input control.

In your HTML file you can define it as:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">The cat was playing in the garden.</textarea>
```

With the corresponding output

[image]

If you want to post the content of the `textarea` to one of the application routes, you should embed the input field inside a form

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">The cat was playing in the garden.</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And you can access it in the route as such:

```
from flask import request
....
@app.route('/')
def home:
   var text = request.form['message']
   return '<h1>{{text}}</h1>'
```

Comment: it did not helped. i added rows and cols result is the same.

Comment: What do you mean "the same". Please explain yourself better, do you want the final output to render new lines or what?

Comment: sorry i think i was unable to explain the issue. i have created an application where user can added cooking recipes. so in the add recipes input form fields if user enter some text for example (This is a famous recipes form latin america. it based on chicken fillet. it is cooked in old traditional way etc so on ) then if we view view the recipe the text is automatically shown in the lines. but if user enter input in the input field like (kkkkkkkkkk) or (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa) and dont give any space in between the letter then in the view section the text appear just one line and overflow the box.